# NodeJS IMAP polling server returns LOGIN failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'd like to check emails every T minutes, using imap module for NodeJS.
So I set a timer:

`_pollingTimer = setInterval(receiveEmails, constants.POLLING_TIME * 60 * 1000); // POLLING_TIME minutes polling`

whereas the `receiveEmails` function is the following:

```
function receiveEmails() {
    const imap = new Imap({
        user: user_name,
        password: user_pwd,
        host: host_name,
        port: host_port_imap,
        tls: true
    });

    imap.once('ready', function () {
        imap.openBox('INBOX', false, function (err, box) { //false means write enable
            if (err) throw err;
            imap.search(['UNSEEN'], function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else if (!results || !results.length) {
                    logger.debug(`No new messages on the INBOX`);
                }
                else {
                    var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: ''});
                    f.on('message', _processMessage);
                    f.once('error', function (err) { console.log('Fetch error: ' + err); });
                    f.once('end', function() {
                        logger.debug(`Done fetching all messages!`);
                        imap.end();
                      });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    imap.once('error', function (err) {
        logger.error(`${err}`);
    });
    imap.once('end', function () {
        logger.debug(`IMAP connection ended`);        
    });

    imap.connect();
}
```

but calling this function multiple times returns LOGIN failed error. It seems related to multiple login attempts.

I tried declaring the imap variable outside the function but nothing changes.

So, how can I periodically check for new emails avoiding reconnections?

Comment: By either [using idle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimap%5D+%5Bnode.js%5D+idle) or opening a new connection. And when you get an error, look at the error message and the commands that led to it.

Comment: I thought that each time I call the receiveEmails function a new connection was opened.

Comment: And when the software does not do what you thought, you might look at the error message and the commands that led to it.